# Implementing resource list in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, resourcebundle

I am porting a JAVA game to WP7. We have lots of images in our game and for loading them in JAVA use a function something like this "Resources.getImage(IMG_BULLETS);" where IMG_BULLETS is ID(an int) of the image.

But in WP7 we have to pass the path(a string) of image in order to load that.

Now my question is :

- How to achieve a int-String mapping? so that I dont have to manually change the Id into path.

One possible solution comes in my mind is to have a .txt file having image path and its Id and parse that. But I am sure their is much better solution for this.

Note : we also have a multi-level folder structure for images and other files.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to refer to resources by int, you are going to have to map them some how to their path. As far as I know, there is no way to crawl your assets, and even if you could, i some how doubt you will get the same index order and you would have to redo your enum.

There are going to be a few hurdles you hit with trying to port and code changes. Another one, (one you will still have even with a txt file work around) will be that the contentManager.Load takes a type, eg, `contentManager.Load<Texture2D>('path')` returning a Texture2D.

One option would be to create your own singleton 'Resources' class that has get methods that take int to get the appropriate asset, however you will still need a mapping via xml or txt file of somekind. However this will require all your assets being loaded from the start which are more problems of their own (90mb memory limit and really long load time).

My advice would be look at the game development section of the [App Hub](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/gamedevelopment) and have a look at the [game state example](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management) to help you see how you might be able to structure your game to work well with XNA.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Layoric. Well return type is not an issue as I have implemented the drawing part. Yes writing 'Resources' class with xml/txt mapping can be a solution but I feel it doesn't mean that you have to load your resource in the start. I will load it when its needed. Please correct me if I am missing something.

Comment: Well, depends how you implement it. If you load your mapping and use the results of it within the Content.Load(<resultofmappingfromint>) then you can do it as needed. This would give more flexibility. When i was thinking about it originally, I was thinking you would probably load all the resources during the parsing of the xml which would be a problem. Unfortunately, this doesn't remove the requirement for a manually mapping on the resources.

Comment: Yes I guess mapping have to be done manually. Will write some script for that :)